# What is the equivalent of the function Digits in Snowflake?

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the Equivalent of the function Digits in Snowflake? 
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about the digits function on IBM DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('abcd');--NULL
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('700000001020577');--700000001020577
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('1234.56');--1234
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('0.56');--0
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('a12#$');--NULL

SELECT IFF(TRY_TO_NUMBER('1234') IS NULL,FALSE,TRUE) --TRUE
SELECT IFF(TRY_TO_NUMBER('abcd') IS NULL,FALSE,TRUE)--FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is [`digits()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_digits.html) from DB2

> The DIGITS function returns a character string representation of the absolute value of a number.

Then something like:

```
REPLACE(ABS(<yourcol>), '.', '')
```

Or:

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(SPLIT(ABS(<yourcol>), '.'),'')
```

If you are also wanting the left-padded zeros there isn't a way to determine precision of a decimal in snowflake directly in your SQL, so you will have to be specific about how large your output string should be.

```
LPAD(REPLACE(ABS(<yourcol>), '.', ''), 10, '0')
```